# Custom fonts for Instagram captions

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I want to create simple app with textview which allow to change fonts attributes (make it bold, italic) and change fonts and then paste this attibuted text to Instagram. For example like from this page https://instagram-fonts.top/cool-text-for-instagram.php.

I try to use textview with attibuted fonts:

```
let range = textViewText.selectedRange
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textViewText.attributedText)
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)]
string.addAttributes(attributes, range: textViewText.selectedRange)
textViewText.attributedText = string
textViewText.selectedRange = range
```

but when I copy and paste this text to Instagram I see usual text without formatting. But in App Store there're plenty of apps which allow change font and font attributes for Instagram. How they get this done?

Comment: I think that those sites do this using unicode symbols

Comment: And how I can release this with textview?